# client (fetch) and server (nodejs http) don't understand each other?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to wrap my mind around nodejs at the moment.

So I've created a client:

```
let myHeaders = {
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'Accept': 'application/json'
};

let myBody = {
  aString: "Test"
};

fetch("http://localhost:8099/", {
  method: 'post',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: JSON.stringify(myBody)
})
.then(result => {
  return result.text();
})
.then(text => {
  // do stuff with text from server
});
```

And I have created a server:

```
// request needed modules
const http = require('http');

// init server
let server = http.createServer(logic);
server.listen(8099);

// server logic
function logic (req, res) {
  var body = req.body;
  res.end("Hello");
}
```

Two problems:

1) The sever does not get the body (req.body is undefined).

**UPDATE**

See my answer below.

**--**

2) The client does not receive "Hello" (result.text() returns "").

**UPDATE**
2 is solved by:

Changing this on the client

```
fetch("http://localhost:8099/", {
  method: 'post',
  mode: 'no-cors', <-- CHANGE to: mode: 'cors'
...
```

Adding this on server

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
```

**--**

I don't get what I do wrong here...

Comment: At first glance, I think you may need `res.send()` instead of `.end()` when sending the response from server.

Comment: What does the server show when you go to http://localhost:8099/ in your web browser?

Comment: Thx for quick answer. `res.send()` is not a valid function. Do you refer to `res.write()`? If yes: Already tried, makes no difference. Plus: In all nodejs courses (e.g. learnyounode) it is stated that `res.end()`is a valid option to write to stream and end it directly after the write happened.

Comment: @pfg it gives back "Hello"... (visible in browser window)

Comment: @MarMun Are there any errors outputted to the console?

Comment: @pfg unfortunately not. No errors at client or in server console...

Comment: @wrangler the client is vanilla js (not nodejs). So I use(?) the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: @wrangler Done. Sorry about that.

Comment: Not related, but unless you have a very good reason not to, I strongly recommend you use Express (expressjs.com)

Comment: @jcaron you are right. I will definitely do exactly that. I just play around to learn the basics atm. Thx for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Node.js code has nothing which would generate the HTML document containing the JS that calls `fetch`.

This means you must be making a cross-origin request (this is supported by the absolute URL you pass to `fetch`).

You also set `mode: 'no-cors'` which means "Don't throw a security exception for trying to access a cross-origin resource, and don't make the response available to JS".

Consequently, when you try to read the response: You can't.

---

Set the mode to `"cors"` and change the Node.js code to [follow the CORS specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to grant permission to the page trying to read the data.

---

> I try to wrap my mind around nodejs at the moment.

There is nothing particular to Node.js here. The problems are related to security restrictions on what JavaScript running in the browser can do unless granted permission by the HTTP server.

Comment: Thx very much for your answer. I've added 

`res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');`

but get error `Failed to load http://localhost:8099/: Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

However, if I access the server via jquery ajax, I get the "Hello" text back...

Comment: I guess it will make sense to tackle the problem from a different angle as well: I have installed local-web-server (from npm) to have the requesting html page (which contains the js client) at the same domain (localhost) <- Doesn't help so far (still the error from my last comment) but I guess this "is the way to develop locally", so I keep trying..

Comment: @MarMun — Presumably, when you use jQuery, you aren't including the `Content-Type: application/json` header that the error message tells you is a field you are not allowed to change.

Comment: @MarMun — Origins need to have the same URL scheme, hostname, and port. Running another HTTP server on localhost but on a different port will still give you a different origin.

Comment: You are a genius. I now get "Hello" also with fetch api (I've removed "Content-Type: application/json").

Comment: Regarding "Origins need to have the same URL scheme, hostname, and port.": Thx for this hint as well. I will look into the topic more deeply.

Comment: One last note: If I set `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');`on server, I can keep `'Content-Type': 'application/json',` in headers of request.

Comment: @MarMun — Yes, you can.

Answer (score 0):

To not completely mess up my question, I post my solution for problem number one as separate answer:

**SOLUTION** 1) The sever does not get the body (req.body is undefined)

As **request is a stream,** I need to treat it like one (notice "req.on('data'...)

This is how the server works as expected:

```
// request needed modules
const http = require('http');

// init server
let server = http.createServer(handler);
server.listen(8099);

// server logic
function handler (req, res) {

  // Set CORS headers
  let headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST, OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'Content-Type, Accept'
  };
  res.writeHead(200, headers);

  if(req.method == 'POST'){

    var body = '';

    req.on('data', data => {
      body += JSON.parse(data).aString;
    });

    req.on('end', () => {

      res.end(body.toString().toUpperCase());
    });

  } else if (req.method == 'OPTIONS'){

    res.end();
  }

}
```